# Why is a MERV-16 filter not recommended for residential furnace use? Urban myth?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, furnace, heat-pump, filter

Someone from an HVAC duct cleaning company told me today that MERV-16 charcoal filters are harder on the furnace and that the charcoal is a gimmick that just costs more.  He said he went to a class and everything, making it sound like MERV-16 was a bad idea.  He said that air flow will suffer and threfore heating/cooling efficiency will to.

Ultimately he recommended MERV-13 because it will put less pressure on the blower motor.

Since my sensitive nose *does* notice the difference, I did some digging on the Lennox filters we have been using and found [this pdf](https://tech.lennoxintl.com/C03e7o14l/VIu12Ch2uV/ehb_hcc_1912.pdf) where, on page 5, Lennox provides the specs for a MERV-13 and the actual MERV-16 model we have been using (Lennox X6672).

Our filter is the 16x25x5" model, which is the center column on the two spec sheet images below.  Note that the CFM rating for both MERV-13 and MERV-16 are the same.  There is a small difference in "Initial" pressure drop but the final pressure drop for both is 0.40 in. w.c. as you can see below.

According to [our furnace's installation document](https://pascalliedcdnep.azureedge.net/airease/RESI_GASFURNACES_A952V-95G2V-UPFLOW_INSTALLATIONMANUAL.pdf), *"This furnace is not certified for operation [...] with an external static pressure which exceeds 0.8 inches w.c."* and both filters shown below max out at 0.40 in. w.c. and page 42 of the [furnace install document](https://pascalliedcdnep.azureedge.net/airease/RESI_GASFURNACES_A952V-95G2V-UPFLOW_INSTALLATIONMANUAL.pdf) (page 48 of the PDF) indicates that CFM maxes out at about 1365 @ 0.50 in. w.c. (I think, don't actually know our blower size). So if I understand correctly the filters below should work fine since they spec a CFM of 800-1600.

In case you it matters: this furnace serves 8 vents upstairs with 2 returns, and downstairs there are 2 vents with 2 returns with a total space of ~2200 sqft and 8' ceilings.

**Questions:**

- Given the two filters shown below, is there really a difference between the two that would affect furnace performance?
- Other considerations?

**MERV 13 Specs**

[image: Lennox MERV13 Filter Specs]

**MERV 16 Specs**

[image: Lennox MERV16 Filter Specs]

Comment: The furnace's static pressure limit applies to all static pressures combined, not just that which derives from the filter.

Comment: Someone from an HVAC duct cleaning company *should've* told you that if you use any type of media filter like that then you never have to call them for anything. And since your sensitive nose does notice the difference, then you're going to use 16s no matter what extra strain it puts on the blower, right? The filter on the unit is to protect the unit. If you want to abuse your air-handler as an air filter, go nuts (not that it really does) but if you're *serious* about air quality, get a TFP. https://hvac-talk.com/vbb/threads/97676-Lifebreath-air-cleaner

Comment: Can you get your duct static pressures measured?

Comment: In my experience most HVAC people operate on rules of thumb.  It's a good rule of thumb to not use a filter way outside the range of "normal" without careful design and measurement.  Give your guy the benefit of the doubt ... he doesn't know how to properly install a MERV 16 filter on your furnace, and he knows well enough not to try it randomly.   But YOU seem to know enough to do this properly.   A manometer costs $50 and you can learn to use it on youtube.  You don't have to follow rules of thumb, you can learn, and measure, and MAYBE you can use these filters!   .......

Comment: It's also possible your guy has enough experience to know without measuring that THIS filter on THIS furnace won't work.  You could find out by asking the right questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More static pressure = Blower motor dies sooner**

If it's worth it to you to replace your blower motor every few years then go ahead and do as you please. The tech just doesn't want to be at fault due to your negligence.

Your furnace has an acceptable static pressure range so get a reading before and after installing the MERV-16. Additionally, check the static pressure monthly so that you replace the filter before static pressure reaches damaging levels.

Another option could be to replace your blower with one that can handle greater static pressures.

Comment: Hey @KJ7LNW you seem to be enough into the technicalities of this to buy a $50 manometer and measure the actual pressure in your furnace return chamber with various filters installed.  Try it with vents open or closed as they typically might be by occupants of their rooms.    An early-warning indicator would be rapid cycling of the furnace (gas flame) or A/C compressor or freezing of the A/C coils in the blower.  "Rapid" is relative to "normal" which you hopefully have some sense of.

Answer (score 1):

I am an a/c specialist who works for a large company designing and installing very complex HVAC systems. Thank you very much for supplying the specs on the filter. Having this knowledge allows me to help explain to everyone how their HVAC systems work and answer the MERV 13 is better than a MERV 16. When you talk about static pressure you’re on the right path. Static pressure is the pressure tolerance of your system. The static pressure is determined by the size of your ducting and filter. So yes, if you have incorrect sized ducting with a stronger filter you will increase the static pressure and the wear and tear on your system, you’re better off going with a weaker filter for better air flow. If your system is designed correctly with proper sized ducts and with a MERV 16 filter you will have good static pressure and no issues. Think about it for a minute and it starts to makes sense.

Comment: The furnace has a variable-speed blower that always keeps the static pressure in spec by adjusting the blower RPM, so the static pressure supported by the furnace is never exceeded.  In this scenario, how could it increase wear?